# Discard specific sequence of character when using string method find()

Tags: python, regex, string, find

Is there any way to achieve this in Python 3+?

I have a string `He said: <p>He<i>ll</i>o how are you?` which does include those HTML tags as plain text. The method `find()` returns a index (a position) withing the searched string. Is there perhaps any regex version of `find()` where I could input this `<[^<]+?>` as a regex for finding a tag enclosed in < > (or perhaps its negative lookahead) - and so ignore them to look for the word `Hello` but still get the absolute position within the original string?

For example:

String = `He said: <p>He<i>ll</i>o how are you?`

Function could be `foo(String, "<[^<]+?>", "Hello")` as in `foo(search in this string, exclude characters matching this regex, look for this`

..and get `13` as a position of the word Hello in the original string in return?

Comment: Regex does not support this, you will first have to strip your html tags and work on the resulting plane string

Comment: What do you really want here? The word `Hello` stripped of any tags?

Comment: I want to keep the tags in there but to be able to search Hello in there which is now obstructed by those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.search('(?:<[^<]+?>)*'.join('Hello'), 'He said: <p>He<i>ll</i>o how are you?').start()` returns 12 (13nth character).

If you are not certain that `Hello` is in the string, you should check if `search` returns `None` before calling `start`.